# error after restart apache2

Tags: 14.04, apache2, phpmyadmin

I use ubuntu 14.04,

I remove phpmyadmin and then install again phpmyadmin

in etc/apache2/apache2.conf i add next:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

and when i try restart apache with next command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I get this error:

```
# sudo service apache2 restart
* Restarting web server apache2   
[Wed Jan 20 23:32:22.925567 2016] [alias:warn] [pid 29418] 
AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/conf.d                                                                                                                                                      
/phpmyadmin.conf at line 3 will probably never 
match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
[ OK ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

from `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

The `phpmyadmin` package already created the symlink `/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf` to include `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`.

You get this warning because you are including `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` twice now.

Comment: will try now and back here

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the default settings you don't need to edit any file.